# Install Apache Module X-Sendfile

Tags: macos, xcode, apache

I wanted to install the Apache-Module X-Sendfile as shown in http://elivz.com/blog/single/mod_xsendfile/ on my Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) setup.

After downloading and unpacking the files, I've used the command  `sudo apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c` to run the install.

After fixing the Error "Not a directory" by creating a symlink ([shown in this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58186/how-to-compile-mod-wsgi-mod-fastcgi-etc-on-mountain-lion-mavericks-by-fixing)), a new problem occured :

```
lduer:mod_xsendfile-0.12 lduer$ sudo apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c
Password:
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=compile /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1   -c -o mod_xsendfile.lo mod_xsendfile.c && touch mod_xsendfile.slo
env: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.9.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: Not a directory
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

I haven't found any solutions by searching the web with the error code.

**Edit 2013-12-13:** I want to mention that the requested Path where the Error *Not a directory* occured (env: `/Applications/[...]/bin/cc`)is a symlink, linking to the file "clang" in the same directory. Maybe this helps to answer the question.

Comment: At the risk of 'Me too' did you figure this out? Having the same problem with Mavericks server.

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet.

I've edited the question and added some additional informations - maybe someone can help??

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I installed the module:

1. Download source code from [mod_xsendfile github repository)[https://github.com/nmaier/mod_xsendfile/releases]
2. Install a newer Apache via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), i.e. `brew install httpd` (note: it will not remove or damage your current, Apple-provided apache install)
3. Go to `sbin` in apache dir, i.e. `/usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.2.23/sbin`
4. Compile the module (as fat-module variant):

   ```
   ./apxs -cia -Wc,"-arch i386 -arch x86_64" -Wl,"-arch i386 -arch x86_64" /path/to/mod_xsendfile.c
   ```
5. Restart apache.

Comment: Yes, the "secret" here is to give up trying to modify the Apple installed Apache and put your own in place. It is then **much** easier to get extras working. Always my first advice.

Answer (score 0):

1. create your own `apxs` script:
   https://gist.github.com/dnozay/a08d4ee903af37832174
   this will fix the CC path that is hardcoded in the `apxs` and `libtool` script.
2. run `sudo ./apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c`